# How do you run a shell command/script automatically when entering/cd-ing a directory on Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, command-line, shell-script, rvm

Apologies if the answer to this is obvious, but I haven't been able to find one yet (perhaps because I'm searching with the incorrect terminology).

I am on a Mac running Snow Leopard and I would like to know if it is possible to have a shell command (or a script) run automatically when I enter/cd into that directory.

An example to better illustrate my question: 
I use [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) for managing versions of Ruby. It employs a similar tactic with it's project [.rvmrc](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/) files. These files are run when the directory they are contained in is entered in order to use the correct version of Ruby for that specific project.

I would like to do something similar in order to display the contents of a todo.txt file when I enter that files containing directory.

Comment: *Entering* as in `cd`ing there?

Comment: Yep "Entering" == "cd-ing"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
function cd {
    # actually change the directory with all args passed to the function
    builtin cd "$@"
    # if there's a regular file named "todo.txt"...
    if [ -f "todo.txt" ] ; then
        # display its contents
        cat todo.txt
    fi
}
```

It's possible you already have a similar function for `cd` — just extend that one to print the contents of `todo.txt` if it exists.

Comment: This won't work with `popd` and `pushd` if you use those. Change them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! I tried adding the above method to my ~/.bash_profile, but it seems as though the builtin cd method is still being called rather than my custom cd method. I created a test method in my ~/.bash_profile to confirm that methods added there are being called and indeed they are.

Comment: @Mark in that case, something else modifies your `cd` again, as I hinted at in my answer — I posted only after confirming it to work for me. Find your current `cd` definition by entering `shopt -s extdebug ; declare -F cd`. Also, you need to new shell session or manually load `.bash_profile` again for the changes to come through.

Comment: @Daniel it seems that RVM is the culprit. The output from running that command resulted in the following: "cd 43 /Users/mark/.rvm/scripts/cd". Looking at that script I can see that it is doing something along the lines of what you are suggesting (it also runs the `builtin cd "%@"` command). If I modify my ~/.rmvrc file I can turn off that functionality which then allows my custom cd method to run, but then I lose RVM's custom functionality. I will have to read RMV's documentation to try and discover whether I can utilise both custom cd functions somehow.

Comment: @Mark You should be able to add the `if` part of my function definition to the `cd` function in that file as I mentioned in the last sentence of my answer. Depends on how they implement their functionality, though.

Comment: @Daniel I fixed the problem by creating a file in my ~/.rvm/hooks/ directory called "after_cd" which is run by RVM itself when the `cd` function is called. If anyone is interested in how RVM handles directory changes a great answer can be found by it's creator [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605277/how-does-rvm-detect-when-youve-changed-directories)