# Use msysgit/"Git for Windows" to navigate Windows shortcuts?

Tags: windows, bash, msysgit

I use msysgit on Windows to use git, but I often want to navigate through a Windows-style `*.lnk` shortcut.  I typically manage my file structure through Windows' explorer, so using a different type of shortcut (such as creating hard or soft link in git) isn't feasible.  How would I navigate through this type of shortcut?

For example:

```
PCUser@PCName ~
$ cd Desktop

PCUser@PCName ~/Desktop
$ ls
Scripts.lnk

PCUser@PCName ~/Desktop
$ cd Scripts.lnk
sh.exe": cd: Scripts.lnk: Not a directory
```

Is it possible to change this behavior, so that instead of getting an error, it just goes to the location of the directory?  Alternatively, is there a command to get the path in a `*.lnk` file?

**EDIT**: I've heard that [the inverse of this exists](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-02/msg01260.html) for cygwin, allowing you to create a symlink which works with explorer.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but if you use the `mklink` command to create an NTFS soft link I think it'll work like you want it to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### *ahem*

First, [compile](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) the following [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com/) script:

```
FileGetShortcut, %1%, shortcut_target
FileAppend, %shortcut_target%, *
ExitApp
```

---

Place the `.EXE` file in a [%PATH%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) directory. I named mine `follow.exe`.

Now, you can effectively follow a Windows `.LNK` file in your working directory by using the following syntax:

```
cd `follow Shortcut.lnk`
```

where `Shortcut.lnk`'s **target** is a valid directory.

---

### Demonstration:

[image: shortcut]

[image: git bash]

---

Once you've set up your `follow.exe`, you can add the following shell function to your `~/.bashrc` file to simplify the syntax even further. <sup>*Thanks, [Daniel](https://superuser.com/questions/408585/use-msysgit-git-for-windows-to-navigate-windows-shortcuts#comment469290_411363)!*</sup>

```
function cd
{
    if [[ ".lnk" = "${1:(-4)}" && -f "$1" ]] ;
        then builtin cd "$( follow "$1" )" ;
    else builtin cd "$1" ;
    fi
}
```

Now, you can follow `.LNK` files with just `cd`!

```
cd Shortcut.lnk
```

---

### Demonstration:

[image: cd]

Comment: This is great!  I was actually learning about using the tick mark syntax to evaluate commands, but this answer provides the exact step I was missing.  Thanks!!  I'm just curious about one thing -- does this work for network mapped drives and/or network locations?  I don't particularly need it for this, but it would be useful to know. :)

Comment: If you can `cd` to the **target** as set in the shortcut file (e.g. see first screenshot), then it should work. This just saves you a couple of steps with the help of AutoHotkey. :)

Comment: Very cool. Using a cd shell function you could automatically do this when cding to lnk files.

Comment: @DanielBeck If you could add steps for setting up a shell function, that would be great!

Comment: No Bash on Windows available right now to test, but [it works like described here](http://superuser.com/a/283365/22317). This might work for the function definition: `function cd { if [[ ".lnk" = "${1:(-4)}" && -f "$1" ]] ; then builtin cd "$( follow "$1" )" ; else builtin cd "$1" ; fi }`. If you cd a *file* named `*.lnk`, use `cd` with `follow`, otherwise use regular `cd`.

Comment: @DanielBeck It works! We've made a breakthrough in Windows+Bash. :)

Comment: @Darthfett See the updated answer.

Comment: Nice demonstration, seems to work quite well. Nothing primitive about this solution anymore :-)

Comment: @iglvzx this is excellent!  I'm considering looking into auto-completion for the resulting directory, this works so well. :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it's not possible at this moment, and the recommended approach is to use the [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) utility:

> [About creating symbolic on msys](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.msys/5060)

**Update:**

Thank you [iglvzx](https://superuser.com/users/100787/iglvzx) for your answer.

However, in my case sometimes the bash autocompletion puts an `/` after the shortcut, like `cd /f/downloads/scripts.lnk/`, so I use it as an excuse to play with bash scripting and adjust your script, also checking for not acceptable shortcuts (broken or pointing to files):

```
cd() {

    shopt -s nocasematch

    if [[ -z "$1" ]];
        then
            echo Error: missing operand;
            return 1;
    fi;

    if [[ "$1" == "/" ]];
        then
            destination=$1;
        else
            destination=${1%/};
    fi;

    extension=${destination##*.}

    if [[ -f "$destination" && $extension == "lnk" ]];
        then

            finaldestination=`follow "$destination"`;

            if [[ -z "$finaldestination" ]];
                then
                    echo Error: invalid destination;
                    return 2;
            fi;

            if [[ -f "$finaldestination" ]];
                then
                    echo Error: destination is a file;
                    return 3;
            fi;

            builtin cd "$finaldestination";

        else
            builtin cd "$destination";
    fi;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could also give bounty to your answer, as it does answer the question, that it doesn't exist.  This is great to know, but the issue is that I don't find file management to be simpler in a terminal -- I manage my files and shortcuts with explorer, and thus cannot simply create a symlink.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Good idea to ignore any trailing `/` characters.  MinGW seems to add a trailing space for me.  I think `sh.exe` already does the destination checking for you, so that's unnecessary work for the script.  What would be interesting to see would be auto-complete for the target directory.

Answer (score 2):

Opening shortcuts from within `msys` is possible with `cmd` via the `/C` flag:

```
cmd //C "C:\Shortcut.lnk"
```

If it's a shortcut to a folder, it will be opened. The slash [has to be escaped](https://superuser.com/q/526736/49388) so msys doesn't convert `/C` to `C:\`.

Relative paths work as well, and quotes aren't needed for simple paths. If the `lnk` file is in current folder:

```
cmd //C Shortcut.lnk
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, awesome approach 
[iglvzx](https://superuser.com/users/100787/iglvzx) ! I recommend a tiny improvement to your `~/.bashrc` script so that a simple `cd` without any argument still changes to the user's home directory.

```
function cd
{
    if [[ ".lnk" = "${1:(-4)}" && -f "$1" ]] ;
        then builtin cd "$( follow "$1" )" ;
    elif [[ -z "$1" ]] ;
        then builtin cd ;
    else 
        builtin cd "$1" ;
    fi
}
```

Comment: If this is an improvement to another answer -- which it looks like it is, well done! -- you could [submit it as an edit](https://superuser.com/posts/411363/edit) to that answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you make a symlink (using `mklink /D <link name> <target dir>` from cmd with admin privileges) instead of a shortcut, git bash can follow it with `cd -P <link name>`.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but originally I was trying to manage my shortcuts strictly through the GUI, and there's no simple solution in the GUI to create a symlink.  Perhaps making that process easier would be an alternative way to get similar behavior in the GUI and command line.

Comment: That's a good point. You can't create symlinks in the file explorer, but you can follow them from the file explorer as you would a shortcut. BTW, I think this only works on windows 10.