# How to run internal cmd command from the msys shell?

Tags: command-line, msysgit, msys

The Windows `CMD` utility has a number of internal commands, such as `mklink`. How can they be used from the `msys` shell ?

From [`CMD`'s documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true), the `/c` switch can be used to execute a command and 
exit; but this doesn't seem to work.

- If I do `cmd /c mklink` the `mklink` command is not executed and the `CMD` shell is not exited.

Before pressing Enter:

[image]

After:

[image]

Process Monitor screenshot:

[image]

- Trying to run the command as a background process: `cmd /c mklink &` apparently works - the `mklink` command is executed, but the `CMD` shell is not terminated. Every time `Enter` is pressed, `CMD` will become the active shell.

Comment: `cmd /c mklink` works for me with my C shell, with Cygwin `bash` and with `cmd.exe`.  But I did have to be running elevated or else I got complaints, "You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation."  I haven't tried `msys` because I don't have it installed but I'm skeptical that's the problem.  I'm suspicious there's something else going on. A transcript or a screen shot of what you did and what happened might be helpful.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, screenshots added. For `mklink` to work, the shell does indeed need to be run as administrator; but my problem is that I can't run any of the internal commands without the `cmd` shell either taking over or running in the background. This issue is also present for simpler commands which do not require admin, such as `dir`.

Comment: Do you have an alias, procedure definition or script that may be intercepting `cmd`?

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, nope; I took @Maxiums' advice and ran Process Monitor, and as can be seen in the screenshot I attached, the issue is that `msys` converts `/c` to `c:\ `. The answer is to escape it, and run the command as `cmd //c mklink`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Search your %PATH% for cmd.cmd or cmd.bat. They may interfere with your cmd
2. Run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and run your `cmd /c mklink`. Examine ProcMon log for really executed commands.

Comment: Process Monitor helped track down the issue. It is that `msys` will convert `/c` to `c:\ `; it needs to be escaped: `cmd //c mklink`. The way these conversions are done is explained [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion).

Comment: @MihaiRotaru this comment should be an answer

Answer (score 3):

win7/cygwin/bash had same problem, solution is to launch cmd twice,
and convert slashes to backslashes as needed by cmd (for example):

  `REPO_DIR=${REPO_DIR////\\}   # Example, Turn c:/cvs into c:\cvs for cmd

  cmd /C "cmd /C mklink /D .Repo $REPO_DIR"  # launch cmd /C cmd /C cmd`

Answer (score 2):

> Process Monitor helped track down the issue. It is that `msys` will convert `/c` to `c:\` ; it needs to be escaped: `cmd //c mklink`. The way these conversions are done is explained [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion). – Mihai Rotaru [Jan 1 '13 at 21:32](https://superuser.com/questions/526736/how-to-run-internal-cmd-command-from-the-msys-shell?rq=1#comment635403_526777)

I could not get this to work based on [Mihai's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/526736/how-to-run-internal-cmd-command-from-the-msys-shell?rq=1#comment635403_526777) alone, because the path still contained forward slashes `/` in it, and `mklink` complained that `/msys64` was not a valid switch.

So I wrote a batch script to get it working.

Here's how I call my batch script from MSYS:

```
 $ mingw_ln.bat "$destination" "$targetpath"
```

And, the batch script takes those two paths, and converts `/` to `\`, using the `:OLD=NEW` parameter expansion syntax for string replacements.<sup>1</sup>

```
set LINK=%1
set TARGET=%2

REM Convert POSIX paths to Windows paths
set LINK=%LINK:/=\%
set TARGET=%TARGET:/=\%

mklink /D %LINK% %TARGET%
```

<sup>1</sup> This is similar to bash's `${PARAM:/OLD/NEW}` syntax, for those familiar with it

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Mihai Rotaru's comment:

> Process Monitor helped track down the issue. It is that `msys` will convert `/c` to `c:\` ; it needs to be escaped: `cmd //c mklink`. The way these conversions are done is explained [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion). – Mihai Rotaru [Jan 1 '13 at 21:32](https://superuser.com/questions/526736/how-to-run-internal-cmd-command-from-the-msys-shell?rq=1#comment635403_526777)

This `/c` to `c:\` conversion can also be avoided for some or all arguments by using the environment variable `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL`.

E.g.

```
$ MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL='*' /c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C "echo foo"
```

(Careful since `'*'` and `"*"` will mean different things.)

Citing the [MSYS2 docs](https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/):

> `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL` can either be `*` to mean exclude everything, or a list of one or more arguments prefixes separated by `;`, like `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=--dir=;--bla=;/test`
> [...]