# msys2 create a sym link into windows folder location

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, msys

I have just started to use msys2. I wanted to make a sym link to a folder on my d:. I can access it like this:

`cd /d/mytestfolder/`

I tried:

- When I do `ln -s /d/mytestfolder/ testfolder` - this seems to be working, but takes a long time, then I realized it just makes a copy and not a link at all :(
- I also tried `cmd /c mklink /c/mytestfolder` (found that somewhere on the web)... no joy
- I even tried (in windows explorer) making a windows short cut. I can see that file, but it does not work with `cd`.

So how can I make a link/shortcut to to my folder?

Comment: duplicate of `http://superuser.com/questions/550732/use-mklink-in-msys`

Comment: @matzeri - hey, that is actually where I got `cmd  /c 'mklink link target'` from.... but that did not work :(

Comment: mklink is a windows command. It does not understand `/c/mytestfolder`

Comment: @matzeri - cool, `cmd /c 'mklink link c:\mytestfolder'` worked, thanks. You can put that up as an answer if you want...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same as
[Use mklink in msys](https://superuser.com/questions/550732/use-mklink-in-msys)

reminding that mklink is a windows command, so it does not understand `/c/mytestfolder` but `c:\mytestfolder` must be used

```
cmd /c 'mklink link c:\mytestfolder'
```

Answer (score 4):

In order for MSYS2 to use native Windows symlinks you need to set:

```
export MSYS=winsymlinks:nativestrict
```

Then `ln -s` creates dir or file symlinks:

```
ln -s $USERPROFILE/tmp ~/tmp

cd ~
cmd /c dir
2022-12-09  01:04    <SYMLINKD>     tmp [C:\Users\user\tmp]
```

Unfortunately, there is no way you create directory junctions from MSYS2 env.

To avoid stupid Windows security restrictions, you need to enable **developer mode**:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "1"
```

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/
Windows 10 Creator Update allows creation of symlinks for apps with privileges
non-elevated to admimistrator if **Developer Mode** is enabled.